# Getting country code through form in php . intl-tel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, intl-tel-input

Hi there I need help in getting the value of the country code in a PHP variable. 
I am using a Jquery plugin named "[International Telephone Input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)".

Here is my input and scripts.

```
   <div class="group">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="phone" > -->
    <!-- Changes -->
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No." 
style="color: #916409;"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar">
</span>
<label style="color: #916409;"></label>
</div>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="src/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#phone").intlTelInput();
</script>
```

I want the country code value so that I can send it to database.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is documented on the [README](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/README.md#events):

```
$("#phone").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
  // do something with countryData
});
```

When the *countrychange* event fires, `countryData` will contain an object with the country data:

```
{
    "name": "United States",
    "iso2": "us",
    "dialCode": "1",
    "priority": 0,
    "areaCodes": null
}
```

This all happens client side, in the browser. In order to get it into a Php variable you will need to submit it within an HTML form or an ajax request. 
For example, using [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) from jQuery you could do something like:

```
$("#phone").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
  $.post("getCountryCode.php", {countryCode: countryData.iso2});
});
```

In getCountryCode.php you can get the value using the [$_POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [super global](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

```
$_POST['countryCode']; // "us"
```